# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jetson.GPIO

Tags: python, pip, nvidia-jetson

Having issues trying to install the Jetson GPIO library. I keep getting this error

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/9e/6cc2823002a6d639217b382e8e3a06200acda7331e1dd7c91fcd31bce641/Jetson.GPIO-0.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=53334f5fa568b3cb722673cc787a310885f38ad9b33df277cf1d8ead2e31396a (from https://pypi.org/simple/jetson-gpio/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Jetson.GPIO (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14, 2.0.15, 2.0.16, 2.0.17)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Jetson.GPIO

Upgrading pip to 22 just gives me a:
**metadata-generation-failed python**
error

I have also tried different versions of python(3, 3.6, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10) but none seem to work.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that gives you that error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am doing: pip install Jetson.GPIO

in order to download the package. I get the above error when pip fails to download the package.

Answer (score 0):

If I had read the whole documentation I would have noticed that the package is meant for a Linux system.

I fixed my problem by opening up ubuntu and running

```
sudo pip install Jetson.GPIO
```

This windows ??equivalent?? also works:

I downloaded the Jetson.GPIO tar file from pypi and extracted it. Then I cd into this directory using the command line and ran this command:

```
python setup.py install
```

I got an error that said

ValueError: path 'lib/python/' cannot end with '/'

I fixed this by editing the setup.py file and removing the '/'. After running the command again it worked.